# Add a new Crystal Report to a Visual Studio 2012 project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I have already installed Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 13.0.5 on my machine, but I do not see an option for me to add a new Crystal Report to my project in Visual Studio 2012.  What step am I missing?  The only question I see on SO to address this suggests I have to uninstall and reinstall VS2012; this does not seem like the right answer to me.

Comment: So, you installed VS 2012 and then installed CR for VS 13.0.5, and now when you create a new Windows Forms application, there is no option for a new Crystal Report or Crystal Report Viewer in the Toolbox -- is this what you're saying? If so, you may need to just add them to the Toolbox manually.

Comment: @Ally Almost.  I'm not looking to add a Crystal Reports control; I am looking to add a new, blank Crystal Report file that I will then configure in VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up updating VS, and the Crystal Report object was available again.